# Java spends extensive time on garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm writing a Java application (it is monitoring some files on disk and based on changes writes stuff to a database), but I noticed it spends considerable amount of time on garbage collection. A snippet of my logfile is below; about each minute it spends a second on garbage collection, and this is while the application shouldn't be doing very much. I launched Java with

```
java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -verbose:gc -jar myApplication.jar
```

and the logfile is given as

```
19:38:15 pong
[Full GC 905059K->593250K(1013632K), 0.9315089 secs]
19:38:28 pong
...
19:39:34 pong
[Full GC 864134K->595982K(1013632K), 0.9592708 secs]
19:39:47 pong
....
19:40:36 pong
[Full GC 875598K->623414K(1013632K), 1.2895245 secs]
19:40:39 pong
```

I could probably switch to a better garbage collector, which doesn't pause my program, but I am more curious why it spends so much time on collecting. edit: I only get the major garbage collections, I don't see minor collections.

What's the best way to debug this?

Comment: "and this is while the application shouldn't be doing very much" - which might be why the GC happens then....

Comment: but then it shouldn't be able to reduce from 900 MB to 600 MB, right?

Comment: without seeing your code, I have no idea.

Comment: can you just paste which type of objects take more mrmoey. jmap -histo:live <pid>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a memory profiler.

It appears you have a large amount of static memory, 600 MB.  The full collections can be a result of creating a lot of objects (too much to fit in survivor space) If you use a memory profiler it should be more obvious.

Something simple you can do is to try and increase the young generation space. e.g. -ms800m -mx1200m -XX:NewSize=500m.  This may change the behaviour and make profiling the application easier.

Comment: In fact, decreating the young generation solved the problem; I'm using -XX:NewRatio=4 now and now all the old stuff comfortably fits into the "old generation" - it appeared that all the stuff that's going to live forever was just too big for the old generation and the JVM tried to GC it all the time.